# Does the meaning of 靓丽 change depending on how 靓 is pronounced？

Tags: meaning

I find for 靓丽：

liànglì
jìnglì

With the difference in pronunciation, is there a difference in meaning?

Comment: bkrs：liàng is 〈方〉 dialect
jìng lì
beautiful
pretty
艳丽。

jìng
〈书〉妆饰；打扮。另见liàng。
◆ 靓
liàng
〈方〉漂亮；好看：靓仔 | 靓女。另见jìng。

Comment: ＂现代汉语词典＂liàng （方）漂亮；好看：～｜～女。别见６７２页 jìng［靓女］（方）漂亮的女子（多指年轻的）［靓仔］（方）漂亮的小伙子。
靓   jìng（书）妆饰；打扮。别见７９２页liàng
［靓妆］（书）美丽的妆饰 1st is  dialect, 2nd  is literary

Comment: regarding below answer, compound 靓丽 not in 现代汉语词典，therefore apparently of low usage frequency，but (see comment #1) no difference in meaning

Comment: @user6065,  Indeed, 靓丽 IS in 现代汉语词典.

Comment: comment #3 refers to the 1978 edition (one that can be borrowed for outside use from a library), since it is e.g. in bkrs users suspect that it would be in later editions

Comment: @user6065, ok, the one I posted here is the 7th edition, the latest one.

Answer (score 2):

According to the 两岸 dictionary, the pronunciation for 靓丽 works like this:

> 【臺拼】jìnglì
>
> 【陸拼】liànglì

So this is mostly a Taiwan vs. Mainland pronunciation difference.

According to the *Students Dictionary of Classical and Medieval Chinese* normally jìng means:

> 1 make up one’s face (woman), apply cosmetics, rouge.
>
> a) prink, adorn, embellish, trim.
>
> 2 ⦿ 靜 jìng 1, quiet, still, tranquil, calm.

While according to *KEY* liàng means:

> {dialect} attractive, good looking, pretty, handsome, beautiful

Longman's also notes:

> 〈粵〉
>
> ❶ 漂亮﹐好看：靚女／靚樣。
>
> ❷ 美味的：靚湯。

So it seems this Cantonese pronunciation has somewhat taken over on the mainland while not influencing Taiwan as much.

Comment: liang/jing, it's all Greek to me!

Comment: @Pedroski Yeah, funnily enough I can never seem to remember how to pronounce 靓 anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Just trying to point out what is indicated by the comment from user6065, the correct pronunciation of 靓丽 is liànglì, not jìnglì. When 靓 is pronounced as jìng, it means 妆饰；打扮. 靓丽 is clearly defined in 现代汉语词典.    [image]